# Finding records not in a join -- Efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I've seen this question a few times, but all the answers rely on having small data sets or limited associations, so here goes again.

I have a has_many_through relationship

```
class ModelA
  has_many :model_c, :through => :model_b
  has_many :model_b

class ModelB
  belongs_to :model_a
  belongs_to :model_b

class ModelC
  has_many :model_a, :through => :model_b
  has_many :model_b
```

I need to clean up 'orphaned' Model B's and Model C's -- in which the Model A has been deleted. So I need to find and delete Model B's without a Model A, and then Model C's without a model B.

We have not been doing this when deleting Model A's because one Model A can be associated to tens of thousands of Model C's and it was taking far too long -- our use of the dependent destroy with a guard block fired off way too many queries and took way too long. We're planning to instead do a nightly cleanup job now.

So, I need to find and delete all ModelB's whose model_a columns contains an ID for a now-non-existant Model A, and delete them.

Solutions I've found so far that won't work for me (because we might have 100's of thousands of orphans at a given time):
- loading all the ids from ModelA.id and ModelB.model_a and doing a set difference 
- loading all the ids from ModelA.id and passing to a "NOT IN" query on Model B
- checking from model C record-by-record

At this point, I think I need a straight SQL solution (which I'm fine with), but I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for.

(DB is MySQL)

Comment: If you want an SQL solution, please rephrase your question in SQL. The shorthand notation you supplied is unreadable for some (most) of the gurus, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested it but I believe this will work if understood [MySQL Multiple-table Delete Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

```
DELETE 
     ModelC, 
      ModelB 
FROM ModelC 
     LEFT JOIN ModelB 
     ON ModelC.BID = ModelB.BID
     LEFT JOIN ModelA
     ON ModelB.AID = ModelA.AID
WHERE
     ModelB.BID is NULL
     OR ModelA.AID IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 `LEFT JOIN` and check for null is the typical SQL way to find missing entries.

Comment: So, this was mostly right, but to get the effect I needed, I had to do  2 queries -- first, delete Model B, then delete Model C. Otherwise, Model C's that have an orphaned Model B, but also good Model B's, would be deleted. We want to preserve Model C's iff they have at least 1 valid connection to a Model A. This got me going, though, thanks.